Is there a way to render a webpage in print-preview mode by default?
I'm developing HTML based smart templates for printed documents. I want to have a setup where I use hot reload of the webpage to view my changes as I'm typing them. So far, this is something I know how to do. But on top of that, I want the browser to display the template like it does in Chrome's print preview: in an A4 canvas, centered in the screen. I want it to look like that because the layout you get with a computer screen is much wider than print, so I don't see the result exactly as it would look like in print. Right now I need to manually activate print preview when my changes reload. I'd like it to be automatic.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I believe I've seen javascript employed to trigger print preview modes. It's usually a button I press to activate it. However, are you asking how to initiate this action from the browser side, or something that is triggered by the site? As in, is this just a testing tool for you, or are you trying to make a website do this for any who visit your website?

@music2myear Imagine a scenario where I have a text editor with my HTML code on one side of the screen, and on the other side a browser window that shows the HTML file and refreshes automatically every time I save my code. I want that browser view to look like a print preview without having to manually invoke it. A JavaScript function that triggers print preview on load could be a good enough solution, however it looks like the print preview prevents hot reload from working (at least in Chrome).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090692/javascript-print-preview

@music2myear Unfortunately, if print preview is opened, then the hot reload stops reloading the page (at least on Chrome).

The print preview is waiting for user input, so chrome is not going to navigate away or update the page until you manually refresh

I wrote a real-time HTML editor, side by side viewable. Frontend wrapped around Ace.js,  It's live preview.  It may get you a step closer.
